# Mini displayport cable max length?

Tags: mini-displayport

I will have a server with a great GPU around 20 meters away from my pc (iMac 27"). I would like to run windows on the server to play from my iMac a game running on the server. (running windows on a server will be the downside of this project).

My monitor is at 2560*1440, will i be able to play at such a resolution over a 20 meter mini display port cable?

Comment: Google is your friend:)

Answer (score 10):

DisplayPort is dynamic and can adapt to cable length, but not quite to the length-resolution pair you want:

[WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Advantages_over_DVI.2C_VGA_and_LVDS):

> - Link training with adjustable amplitude and preemphasis adapts to differing cable lengths and signal quality
>
>   - Reduced bandwidth transmission for 15 meter cable (at least 1920×1080p60, 24 bpp)
>   - Full bandwidth transmission for 2 meter cable

[DisplayPort.org](http://www.displayport.org/faq/):

> **Q: What is the maximum length of DisplayPort cable that supports a resolution of 2560×1600?**
>
> A: 2560 x 1600 (WQXGA resolution) is supported over all 2-meter “DP Certified” cables.  Some cables, due to their design, may be capable of supporting 2560 x 1600 resolution over lengths longer than 2 meters.

You may be able to use an [extender](http://www.touchboards.com/Avenview/AvenviewFO-DP-30-MM.html)/[booster](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?cid=13378434428964412281)/[repeater](http://www.langtoninfo.com/showitem.aspx?isbn=4002888384001)/etc. though:

[icron](http://www.icron.com/products/usb_new/usb-over-displayport-faq.php):

> **Q7: What is the maximum length of a DisplayPort cable?**
>
> A7: Standard DisplayPort cables are up to 15 meters (50 feet) in length. DisplayPort extender technologies, using Cat 5 or Fiber, extend this distance to over 100 meters (330 feet). Icron’s USB over DisplayPort technology is compatible with standard DisplayPort cables and DisplayPort extenders.